# Regarding ascii and python packing

Tags: python, serial-port, base64, pyserial

I do have some problems with python packaging, its generating bytes array from the range of 0x00 to 0xff i suppose, and most of these fall of ascii representation.

I wanna send data in a serial port, few things to be kept in mind is that some of hex values like 0x11 and 0x13 are used by the serial protocol for internal flow control. I need to avoid them by sending.

I can avoid these by sending 2 bytes insted of one, like 0x11 is encoded as 0x7d, 0x31. and
0x13 is encoded as 0x7d, 0x33.
This option complicats at receiving end maintain a temprovary byte array and iteratively check for the accurance of 2 string and convert it back to one. - complex

use base64 encoding - simple but only increases the data to 25% more .. i am using RADIO link .. its really hard i dont know what to do .. help me ..!

Comment: Have you tried working with FITS files?? they are a lot easier to handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you encode and decode bytes in python:

```
>>> '\x41'
'A'
```

If you want to do this with a function use chr(int()):

```
chr(65)
'A'
```

Decode known string:

```
ord('A')
65
```

Hex to int:

```
int('0x41', 16)
65
```

Int to hex:

```
hex(65)
'0x41'
```